# Unable to un-check navigation pane items in folder options

Tags: windows, windows-10

i am using windows 10.

in the folder options, navigation pane options are getting defaulted to expand to open folder and show all folders.

can anyone suggest, please ...

Answer (score 0):

Below are several settings in Explorer that may relate to the problem.

- If you wish to just reset all settings to the default, go to the ribbon
  View pane, click Options, open the View tab and click the button "Reset Folders".
- To turn off "Expand to current folder" in the Navigation Pane,
  right-click in the pane and uncheck the option.
- For "Show all folders", this option is also available as above.
- The expanded state of a folder can be manually undone, but you can also
  reset them all to default using the following command run in an elevated
  Command Prompt:

  ```
  REG DELETE HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\NavPane /V ExpandedState /F
  ```